# Attribute Error :split on spark sql python using lambda

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, split, attributes

In Spark SQL I am using Python and I am trying to work on the output RDD of below sql. It's a list of tweets. I need to split words and extract the @ but when using map and trying to split by spaces I am getting the undermentioned exception message

```
words.tw = sqlContext.sql("SELECT text  FROM tweet where text like '%@%'")
tweetrdd = tw.rdd.map(lambda line: line.split(" "))
tweetrdd.collect()


ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 84.0 (TID 310)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1272, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(item)
**AttributeError: split**
```

Comment: example of your data and expected output would be helpful

Answer (score 4):

When you get rdd from a DataFrame it gives RDD[Row] hence you cannot split over the Row, what you need to do is extract the string from the Row and then perform your split.

You can do something like this:

```
words.tw = sqlContext.sql("SELECT text  FROM tweet where text like '%@%')
tweetrdd = tw.rdd.map(lambda line: line.text.split(" "))
tweetrdd.collect()
```

**P.S**: I am a Scala guy, hence the syntax can be wrong. But you can get the idea of what I am trying to do.

Comment: yes makes sense but same issue with getString unable to identify that also :(

Comment: Can you please paste the error stack trace ! Other than that that is present above'

Answer (score 1):

```
words.tw = sqlContext.sql("SELECT text  FROM tweet where text like '%@%'").rdd.map(list)    
tweetrdd = tw.rdd.map(lambda line: line[0].split(" "))    
tweetrdd.collect()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: I agree to the above comment but the answer helped me a major scratching head from long time. Thanks